# iOS: registerDefaults cause crash

Tags: ios

My app crash on start. Please point me the way. Much appreciated.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
NSDictionary *temp = @{@(0): NSStringFromCGPoint(CGPointZero),
                       @(1): NSStringFromCGPoint(CGPointZero),
                       @(2): NSStringFromCGPoint(CGPointZero),
                       @(3): NSStringFromCGPoint(CGPointZero),
                       };

// Pro
NSDictionary *defaults = @{ // ... other PrefKeys 

                           // No crash if I comment out this line
                           GMListVCOffsetsPrefKey:temp,
                           };

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults: defaults];
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keys in plist must be strings. Here you have numbers.

See [Property list documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH3-SW2): "And although NSDictionary and CFDictionary objects allow their keys to be objects of any type, if the keys are not string objects, the collections are not property-list objects".

Answer (score 2):

You are using non-NSString keys for the temp array which is causing the crash. The code below does not crash.

```
NSDictionary *temp = @{@"0": NSStringFromCGPoint(CGPointZero),
                       @"1": NSStringFromCGPoint(CGPointZero),
                       @"2": NSStringFromCGPoint(CGPointZero),
                       @"3": NSStringFromCGPoint(CGPointZero),
                       };

// Pro
NSDictionary *defaults = @{ // ... other PrefKeys

                           // No crash if I comment out this line
                           GMListVCOffsetsPrefKey:temp,
                           };

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults: defaults];
```